# Is there an equivalent of T-SQL's HASHBYTES('SHA1', VARBINARY(MAX)) in Java?

Tags: java, hash, byte, varbinary, hashbytes

I am using org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils library to calculate the SHA1 hash in Java.
`DigestUtils.sha1Hex("0x808204E039EFB76D96D3780BB507674")`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't give the same result as the below SQL statement?

```
select HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),
0x808204E039EFB76D96D3780BB507674,1))
```

The equivalent of varbinary is byte[] in Java. So, I tried `DigestUtils.sha1Hex("0x808204E039EFB76D96D3780BB507674".getBytes())` but this didn't help either. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `getBytes()`.  It has nothing to do with decoding hex values.

getBytes() returns one or more bytes *for each character* in a String, using the underlying system’s default *charset.*  That charset is almost certainly either UTF-8 or windows-125x, which means all the characters in your String will have a single corresponding byte, due to the way those charsets convert characters to and from bytes.

So, your byte array will have values like this, which is definitely *not* what you want:

```
{
    56, // codepoint for the '8' character
    48, // codepoint for the '0' character
    56, // codepoint for the '8' character
    50, // codepoint for the '2' character
    48, // codepoint for the '0' character
    52, // codepoint for the '4' character
    69, // codepoint for the 'E' character
    // etc.
}
```

“Hex” is short for hexadecimal, or base 16.  In base 16, two digits represent a byte value—that is, a value from 0 to 2⁸−1.  You need to parse *every two digits* into a single byte value.

While there are third party utilities for this, it’s so easy that you’re really better off doing it manually:

```
String s = "0x808204E039EFB76D96D3780BB507674";

// chop off "0x"
s = s.substring(2);

byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray();
```

Now, the byte array will have values that correspond to the bytes represented by your hex digits:

```
{
    8,      // 0x8
    8,      // 0x08
    32,     // 0x20
    78,     // 0x4E
    3,      // 0x03
    -98,    // 0x9E
    // etc.
}
```